# Android AdMob Vertical ads

Tags: android, admob

My app is mostly in a landscape layout and the regular rectangle ads does not fit well with my overall design.

Is it possible to create a vertical ad using AdMob?
I mean an ad that's in the Google skyscraper design (adsense)
As shown in the photo, I'd like my add to be in the shape of the red rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android:rotation="90" on the adView does the trick.

Comment: how do you left align the ad? also won't the text get rotated so that it no longer reads top to bottom?

Comment: not working. any other fix?

Answer (score 1):

AdMob offers only the following banner formats:

> 320x50    Standard Banner
>
> 300x250   IAB Medium Rectangle
>
> 468x60    IAB Full-Size Banner
>
> 728x90    IAB Leaderboard Tablets

You can modify the size of the View that shows the ad, but the documentation says that:

> No ads will be returned if your view size is too small.

Source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate

Comment: But how do I rotate it to be vertical?

Comment: There are also smart banners with other sizes like 32px height and match parent width, etc, these days. PS These seem to have a far lower fill rate.